# How to move a clip aside for possible future use in FCPX?

Tags: final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x

I'm editing a short movie, and there are clips that I'm considering cutting that I want to keep in place but not necessarily use. How can I deactivate a clip such that it doesn't occupy the storyline, but stays in place?

"disabling" a clip (pressing <kbd>V</kbd>) doesn't do that- it still remains a blank part of the timeline. "Lift from timeline" doesn't seem to accomplish that either.

Ideally, I could just leave the clips in place and disable them in a way that makes the playhead skip ahead when it reaches those clips, so that I can easily see what the movie looks like with those optional clips and without them.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd lift the clip from the story line and then disable it with <kbd>V</kbd>. There's no other way to keep a clip in the timeline near the edit point without leaving empty space or affecting the timing of the cut.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but as you can see OP already mentioned this... Please explain your solution more in detail.

Comment: I understood OP as trying either or. Doing both works great. There's not other way to keep a clip in the timeline near the edit point without leaving empty space or affecting the timing of the cut.